# Swift, Casting object as String, result is nil

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I've had some trouble casting two dictionary values to strings for what feels like hours now, basically what i have is socket data (notification!.userInfo) that i need to crosscheck with facebook data, hence i need to cast a key value a string.

What i have below is two values that i need to check if they are equal, i thought casting them to string would render the same result, but one of them becomes nil. Could anyone give me pointers to where i might have cocked up?

I have marked the values 1 and 2 to make it easier to follow.

```
let data: Dictionary = notification!.userInfo!["data"]![0] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

println(data["users"]?["fb_id"]!) //1.
println(FacebookManager.instance.user!["id"]) //2.

println(data["users"]!["fb_id"]! as? String) //1. This is the cast that fails
println(FacebookManager.instance.user!["id"] as? String) //2.
```

**What's printed:**

```
Optional(10202362731884832) //1.
Optional(10202362731884832) //2.
nil //1.
Optional("10202362731884832") //2.
```

**If i print the objects with '_stdlib_getTypeName' i get**

```
_TtSq //1.
_TtSQ //2.
```

So there's definitely some difference, but i'm not sure what it is.

**EDIT:**
If i cast them as NSNumber the one that previously failed will work, and the other will fail (becomes nil) 
I don't know if that makes anything clearer.

**EDIT 2:**
If i cast the failing value to NSString, then get the .stringValue, it will work. Should it always be this retardedly complicated to work with Dictionary values in Swift?

Comment: The `_stdlib_getTypeName` output tells us nothing. According to [this excellent article](http://www.eswick.com/2014/06/inside-swift/), both types stand for the implicitly unwrapped optional type.

Comment: Yes, it's retardedly complicated.
It looks like `fb_id` is a `NSNumber` and you can't cast an `NSNumber` to `String` like you did. You have to call `.stringValue` because you're dealing with an ObjC object. You can do it with a one-liner: `data["users"]?["fb_id"]?.stringValue` but that's as nice as it gets.

Comment: You REALLY need to stop using the force unwrap operator (`!`) everywhere. It will come back to bite you sooner rather than later. Use `if let` or even better `Optional.map()`

Comment: Ah, so you're saying it was an NSNumber all along, thanks for clearing that out, i'm still very new to iOS development. As for the ! operator, i have full control of my backend and what i get from facebook, so it shouldn't be an issue. I do however use it unnecessarily much due to simply debugging, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ah i see now, S = Swift, and Q = Optional. So is there any way to know what a primitives class is in swift? Been looking for a fair while now and can't find anything that wont result in either the above or a 16 character hexvalue

Comment: You can unwrap the optional again with a second exclamation mark (`!!`) and inspect this objects type?